# Creating frame for several box plots

Tags: r

I would like to create a frame for these box plots. How can I put all these 2 box plots in one box or frame in R?

```
     x = c(1,3, 5, 8, 10)
     y=c(2, 5, 6, 7, 9)
     z = c(3, 5, 8, 10, 12)
     par(mfrow=c(1, 3))
     boxplot(x)
     boxplot(y)
     boxplot(z)
```

Comment: `boxplot(x, y)`? Not sure I understand the question....

Comment: As in `boxplot(cbind(x,y))`?

Comment: Actually I want to have two separate box plots, just I would like to create a whole frame, not combining both of them in one plot.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to export the plot and use another tool to create the frame. My usual workflow is RStudio -> Export to PDF -> Edit in Inkscape

If you want to do it programmatically something like this should work:

```
x = c(1,3, 5, 8, 10)
y=c(2, 5, 6, 7, 9)

oldpar <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
boxplot(x)
boxplot(y)

# Modify the margin, so that the box is larger than the plots
par(mfrow=c(1,1), mar=c(1, 1, 1, 1))
box()

# Revert to original params    
par(oldpar)
```

Comment: Thanks for your good reply. If I would like to add another box plot and then add a whole frame for all of them, how can change right side margin since the whole frame gets so close to the last box plot frame. How can I adjust it?

Comment: You may want to explore the `layout` function in that case

Answer (score 1):

This is alternative using `ggplot2` and do some trick on building a desired `data.frame`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

x = c(1,3, 5, 8, 10)
y = c(2, 5, 6, 7, 9)
z = c(3, 5, 8, 10, 12)

data <- data.frame(x,y,z)         #You may add as many variables as you like
DATA <- melt(data)

ggplot(data = DATA, aes(factor(1), value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +  facet_wrap(~variable,scales="free",ncol=8)+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i do not want to use ggplot package.I would like to create it by layout. How can I do this in R?